# Maybe add extra sentence/word to string

Tags: python, string

I've had to create code similar to this several times:

```
if condition():
    word = " not"
else:
    word = ""

print "A five ounce bird could{0} carry a one pound coconut".format(word)
```

I've stripped the problem down to its bones here, in "practice" there'd be extra variables for `"A"`, `"five"`, `"bird"`, `"a"`, `"one"`, and `"coconut"` so that they might all change, and along with them, added plural s-es and whatnot.

It has always struck me as somewhat less than satisfying. The extra space required before `"not"` and the lack of a space before `{0}` both irk, but since I don't want two spaces there if `word` is empty, I can't see any other way to do it.

Creating two separate messages breaks with [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and is sometimes not even viable because of the number of possible combinations.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: It could grip it by the husk...

Comment: Creating two separate messages is the correct way to do it if you ever want to internationalise your program. Internationalisation will also help with the plurals. You should check it out `gettext` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of words, insert if necessary, and then `' '.join(words)` them.

If there are commas/periods, build a sentence structure:

```
[['If', 'there', 'are', 'periods'], ', ', ['build', 'a', 'sentence', 'structure'], '.']
```

with respective spaces in the interpunction (space after comma, space before parenthesis,…) and then `' '.join()` the words within groups and `''.join()` the individual groups. (Thanks to @Alfe for the suggestion with joining words and groups differently).

Comment: I propose to join the parts over `''` instead of `' '` and put the needed spaces into the string constants (e. g. `', '`).  This way you also can handle opening parentheses (which need the space *before* the character) and the like.

Comment: Instead of denoting `['If', 'there', 'are', 'periods']` I propose to write `'If there are periods'.split()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Creating two separate messages breaks with DRY

If you care about [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization), then creating two separate messages is probably the only reasonable way to do it.

Comment: I just made a comment about this, so I will give you +1

Answer (score 1):

For the `" not"` case, keep it simple:

```
print "A five ounce bird could{0} carry a one pound coconut".format(" not" if condition() else "")
```

Comment: This does not really answer the _question_, which has to do with the space in `" not"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do...

```
word = ("could" if not condition() else "could not")

print "A five ounce bird {0} carry a one pound coconut".format(word)
```

:P

Edit: for the general case, which is what you want, I'd go by composition. Eg. (ok, this is too Go4 and simplistic for my liking, but makes the point):

```
class Agglutinator(list):
    def __str__(self):
        return self._separator.join(str(x) for x in self)


class Paragraph(Agglutinator):
    """Returns dot separated sentences""" 
    _separator = '. '

class Sentence(Agglutinator):
    """Returns comma separated clauses""" 
    _separator = ', '

class Clause(Agglutinator):
    """Returns space separated words"""
    _separator = ' '

c1 = Clause(["A", "number", "of", "words", "make", "a", "clause"])
c2 = Clause(["and", "a", "number", "of", "clauses", "make", "a", "sentence"])
c3 = Clause(["A", "collection", "of", "sentences", "makes", "a", "paragraph"])

s1 = Sentence([c1, c2])
s2 = Sentence([c3])

print Paragraph([s1, s2])
```

which gives you:

```
A number of words make a clause, and a number of clauses make a sentence. A collection of sentences makes a paragraph
```

Elaborating a little bit on it you may make `Sentence` capitalize the first word, etc.

Comment: This would work only for your particular case, but my point is that you shouldn't treat the "not" as a separate particle from "could". That makes live easier.

Comment: Nice way of avoiding the problem. :) It does not, however, solve the _generic_ problem, where this is not always possible or practical.

Comment: About your question to @eumiro ("What if the inserted word should go right before a period?") I'd construct sentences one at a time, and then join them, eg. ".  ".join(sentences). Similar process for commas, etc.

Comment: It's very impressive code at least! But now I'm irked by having to quote each word in the text separately. (I guess there's just no pleasing some people...)

Comment: Oh, come on... That was to make an example showing that you can start from simple components and grow up. I could have `Clause("A number of words make a clause".split())`, for that matter. I was just pointing to building blocks on making a generic solution! :P

Answer (score 1):

Since the rules where a space must be and where not are clear in English (and in other languages I know), you could use a simple list of all sentence parts (e. g. `['If', 'there', 'are', 'commas', ',', 'we', 'insert', 'them', '.']`) and then write a specialised join function which applies English rules on where spaces must be inserted (e. g. between words, after commas, before opening parentheses, …).

Comment: I like the idea, I think it at least preferrable to eumiro's suggestion. Though the need to quote each word separately makes it all these variations less attractive, I think.

Comment: Yeah, again, I propose to use `"one two three".split()` or a specialised `sentenceSplit('one two three, four five six')` which works for punctuation as well as for word boundaries.  You should also consider punctuation like `--`, groups of those like `,"`, `--,`, inter-word punctuation like `don't` and other stuff like hyphens.

Comment: Yeah, natural language is full of nastinesses >;-]

Answer (score 1):

One other way to handle this, but a am not sure if it is what you are looking for

```
word = "not"

print "A five ounce bird could{0} carry a one pound coconut".format(" "+word if condition() else "")
```

Ok, one more approach. But in fact, nearly all of them are similar or same...

```
def format_word(word):
    if word:
        return " " + word
    else:
        return ""

print "A five ounce bird could{0} carry a one pound coconut".format(format_word(word))
```

But probably, all of the will look irking, since they are in fact similar...

Final **dirty** approach might be:

```
if condition():
    word = "not"
else:
    word = ""

wrd =  "A five ounce bird could {0} carry a one pound coconut".format(word)
print wrd.replace("  ", " ") # replace all double spaces with singular one...
```

but yes, it is dirty too...

Comment: This makes the irking space even more prominent.  Is that an advantage?

Comment: Python have a variety ways to do this, but probably each of them will have less or more irking, in your condition...

Comment: It's like putting makeup on a pig -- it doesn't help much. The middle idea is the best of them, though. Hiding uglyness in a single function is way better than having it sprinkeled all over your code.

Comment: All approaches a can offer are just make up on pigs (: As far as i know, using a space before the word(as in your code example) is the way people do that. Otherwise even if you do it in a string formatting class, it will be just hidden but dirtyness will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another possibility that I just thought of myself. Subclass `string.Formatter` and add a custom converter, so you can type

```
fmt = MyFormatter()
print fmt("Problem {not!w} solved", not="")
```

The formatter would then remove the space before all fields with the `!w` converter if the variable was empty/not specified. This requires reimplementing at least the `vformat` and `convert_field` methods, but it should be quite doable.